# (How) Can I find the socket type from the socket descriptor?

Tags: c, networking, sockets

I am writing a program to capture socket network flow to display network activity.
For this, I was wondering if there is any way I can determine the socket type from the socket descriptor.

I know that I can find socket family using getsockname but I could not find a way to find socket type.

For instance, I want to find if this socket was open as UDP or TCP.
Thanks for any advice in advance.

YEH

Answer (score 20):

Since you mention `getsockname` I assume you're talking about POSIX sockets.

You can get the socket type by calling the `getsockopt` function with `SO_TYPE`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void main (void) {
    int fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    int type;
    int length = sizeof( int );

    getsockopt( fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &type, &length );

    if (type == SOCK_STREAM) puts( "It's a TCP socket." );
    else puts ("Wait... what happened?");
}
```

Note that my example does not do any error checking. You should fix that before using it. For more information, see the POSIX.1 docs for [getsockopt()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockopt.html) and [sys/socket.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html).

Comment: getsockname() and getsockopt() are not specific to POSIX.  Microsoft's Winsock API has them as well.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau
Yes, they're both based on the BSD socket layer. There are some critical differences, but such simple usage of getsockopt() is likely to be the same.

Comment: In visual studio, I was forced to convert the fourth argument to **char*** `getsockopt(_Master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, (char*)&type, &length);` `if (type == SOCK_DGRAM) puts("udp"); else puts("tcp");`